# How to recover from a comms/service failure with WCF netTcpBinding?

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I'm developing a client/server app in which the client calls the WCF service every few seconds. I'm not using IIS - the service runs as a console app (with the intention of installing it as a Windows service on production systems).

I started off using basicHttpBinding, and if I stop the service (to simulate a comms/server failure) the client simply ignores the fact that it can't connect to the service, by handling the `EndpointNotFoundException` that gets thrown. After restarting the service, the client is able to start calling it again and everything is good.

I've now switched to using netTcpBinding, and this time when I stop the service it takes a little while for its console window to close (presumably due to the way TCP manages the connection, which eventually times out). At this point the client gets a `CommunicationException` (*"the socket connection was aborted"*). When I restart the service, the client isn't able to "resume" like it did with basicHttpBinding. Each time it tries to call the service it throws a `CommunicationObjectFaultedException` (*"The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state."*).

How would I go about building in some kind of resume/recovery behaviour, similar to what I saw with basicHttpBinding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reuse the channel as it has faulted. You should cast your client to an ICommunicationObject and call Abort() to clean up.

After that you simply start afresh by creating a new client channel. You may want to do this on a timer if your server is down for a period of time.